# SQL Server Connectivity Issues

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the below error on occasion. Maybe every 30mins or so. I am not sure how to track what is causing the issue. I think it could be a Network problem as there are disk backups running as well.

Any suggestions on where to begin? Thanks!

*The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out*

Comment: **First you need to do some research before asking !! Googleup or search on stackexchange.com**
This problem is solved in this stack , check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393398/net-4-5-forms-app-connecting-to-sql-server-2012-fails-ssl-provider-error-0)

Comment: If there's nothing going on in the event logs then throw a perf mon capture session on the disk, nic, CPU, and memory.  That should help localize the problem.

Answer (score 6):

OK, so odds are it isn't link that Up_One posted.

SQL Server does all it's work via schedulers.  Each scheduler is attached to a CPU core on the server.  Usually when I've seen that error it's because the CPUs are very busy and can't properly respond to the request in the time needed.

What's the CPU workload on the SQL Server look like when the problem happens?  How many users are running queries at that time?  How many CPU cores does the server have?

The fix is to reduce the CPU workload on the server.  Typically this is done by doing index tuning on the system which will reduce CPU workload.

Comment: Hi, I have followed [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/use-resource-monitor-for-memory-monitoring/) about tracking performance in Windows Resource Monitor. How do I use Performance Monitor to Track these values over time? e.g.   Disk I/O:
- Measure Response Time(ms)
- Measure Disk Queue Length
Network:
- Measure Network Utilization


Thanks!

Comment: This article http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Using-Windows-7-performance-monitor-to-view-data talks about using perfmon. It's written for Windows 7, but it's basically the same in Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 4):

it seems to be a bug in .net framework

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745004/net-4-5-sql-connection-pre-login-handshake-error